# Question regarding probability

Tags: probability

Question is as follow:

> An online dating service allows users to choose six out of $30$ words to describe their personality. The dating service creates a match based on five of the same words. If client A and client B both choose random personality words, what is the probability they can find a match?

I understand that there are $^{30}C_6$ ways to choose $6$ numbers out of $30$ cards, but I am unsure how to tackle the rest of the problem.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, suppose $A$ has chosen words $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$.  How many choices match these in exactly $5$ terms?  (how many, for instance, have $(a,b,c,d,e)$ but not $f$?)

Comment: Hint: consider two cases separately: if they have all $6$ in common or if they have $5$ in common. In the latter case, count the number of possible selection of $5$ words they could have in common, then count the number of distinct $6$th words they could add to it. Add up all these possibilities, and divide by the total number of choices of $6$ words that can be made by both people.

Comment: @lulu so 25 ways to match (a,b,c,d,e) and so 25 * 6 (for each letter)?

Comment: @TheoBendit so 25*6 / 30C6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just use the hypergeometric distribution on the second person's choices. The first person's choices define $6$ "winners" and $24$ "losers".

The second person must choose either $5$ or $6$ winning words when selecting $6$ words out of $30$

$$ P= \frac {\binom {24}0 \binom 66 }{\binom {30}6}  +\frac {\binom {24}1 \binom 65 }{\binom {30}6}   $$

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359402/question-regarding-probability#comment9102902_4359402)...

Not quite. There are $(^{30}C_6)^2$ ways the *two* people can choose their words. There are $^{30}C_6$ ways they can choose the same $6$ words (one person gets a free choice, and the other is forced into choosing the same $6$ words). There are $^{30}C_5$ ways to choose $5$ words in common similarly, in the second case. The first person then has a choice of $25$ words to make their $6$th, while the second person has a choice of $24$ remaining words. In total,
$$\frac{^{30}C_6 + ^{30}C_5 \cdot 25 \cdot 24}{(^{30}C_6)^2}.$$